# how to get unique year and month list from database "date" column (laravel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, collections, eloquent-relationship

here is my code and its working fine.

```
SubjectReport::selectRaw('YEAR(date) as year, MONTH(date) as month')->distinct()->get();
```

I want to know is it another way to get data from database using eloquent or collection methods?

example:

```
2023-01
2023-02
2023-03
```

Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with selecting like that?

Comment: @afcyy nothing wrong. i just want to see some another way by collection method or another way.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the data in the desired format right at the database level, I think your approach is the way to do it.

An alternative is using [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators) to get the right format (but casting is only applied when converting to array or JSON).

```php
// Add this to your model

protected $casts = [
    'date' => 'date:Y-m'
];
```

```php
// Get the date with right format

$formattedDates = SubjectReport::select('date')->distinct()->get()->toArray();
```